# make .o files in separate folder in linux kernel compilation

Tags: c, linux, compilation, linux-kernel

see in linux kernel compilation if just do make

```
make ARCH=xyz uImage
```

then it will compile files as per your .conf file and create .o or .ko in same folder where your .c file is there.

So is there any way so i can force to compilation so that all .o and .ko will be any in different folder specified by me

Comment: You'll need to edit the makefiles.

Comment: linux kernel basic makefile doenst provide this features?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try using `make O=/path/to/mydir`

Here is the documentation from the kernel's Makefile:

```
# kbuild supports saving output files in a separate directory.
# To locate output files in a separate directory two syntaxes are supported.
# In both cases the working directory must be the root of the kernel src.
# 1) O=
# Use "make O=dir/to/store/output/files/"
#
# 2) Set KBUILD_OUTPUT
# Set the environment variable KBUILD_OUTPUT to point to the directory
# where the output files shall be placed.
# export KBUILD_OUTPUT=dir/to/store/output/files/
# make
#
# The O= assignment takes precedence over the KBUILD_OUTPUT environment
# variable.
```

Comment: thanks worked..i need to do distclean then need to create .conf using this option then created uImage with this option